# Building shapefile for Naples region, Italy

Tags: shapefile, data, italy

I have been searching high and low for a building data layer for the Naples region of Italy (Campania). I am studying volcanic risk from a volcano called Campi Flegrei and have to see how this volcano could affect the resident population. Any suggestions for building/structure polygons and census data would be great. Any sites or open access databases people recommend?

I have been trawling through Italian geo sites for days and cannot seem to find the info as shapefiles. Some previous research has used 133 regional level Campania Region, scale 1:5.000 digitised from pdf, however, their data is not freely available. I could try and digitilise from these pdfs, however, I think this would take months and not be accurate.

Comment: I think this would be better researched/asked at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.